# How to avoid destroying and recreating threads inside loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns

I have a loop with that creates and uses two threads. The threads always do the same thing and I'm wondering how they can be reused instead of created and destroyed each iteration? Some other operations are do inside the loop that affect the data the threads process. Here is a simplified example:

```
const int args1 = foo1();
const int args2 = foo2();
vector<string> myVec = populateVector();
int a = 1;
while(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    auto func = [&](const vector<string> vec){
        //do stuff involving variable a
        foo3(myVec[a]);
    }
    thread t1(func, args1);
    thread t2(func, args2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    a = 2 * a;
}
```

Is there a way to have `t1` and `t2` restart? Is there a design pattern I should look into? I ask because adding threads made the program slightly slower when I thought it would be faster.

Comment: More efficient for the programmer, but about the same for the program.

Comment: It may be worth looking up the 'producer - consumer' pattern? Your current loop could simply feed a queue with data to be processed and your thread function could loop waiting for new data to appear in the queue and processing what it finds.

Comment: Watch out. If you have multiple threads simultaneously operating on a `vector`, or just about anything really, the results will be very messy. Some synchronization is a must.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) as suggested in the comments.

What you're also trying to do is a very common usage for a Threadpool. I simple header only implementation of which I commonly utilize is [here](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool)

To use this library, create the pool outside of the loop with a number of threads set during construction. Then `enqueue` a function in which a thread will go off and execute. With this library, you'll be getting a [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) (much like the std::async steps) and this is what you'd [`wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait) on in your loop.

Generically, you'd want to make access to any data thread-safe with mutexs (or other means, there are a lot of ways to do this) but under very specific situations, you'll not need to.

In this case,

1. so long as the vector isn't being increased in size (doesn't need to reallocate)
2. Only reading items  or only modifying each item at a time in its own thread

the you wouldn't need to worry about synchronization.

Though its just good habit to do the sync anyways... When other people eventually modify the code, they're not going to know your rules and will cause issues.

Comment: That is correct, the size of the vector never changes and it's guaranteed that the same element is not accessed at the same time by different threads.

Comment: What exactly is a thread pool and how does it differ from the producer-consumer pattern? I've found most articles give a very abstract description https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool

Comment: A thread pool is simply the idea that you create a fixed number of threads and then each thread has its own loop. At the start of the thread's loop they pick up a job to do, then do it and wait for the next job.

Comment: Where would the async go to eliminate the recreation of threads?

Comment: If you were to a threadpool, you wouldn't use async. [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) can be called on different functions (you'll also get futures) and then you'd wait on those futures. Its "implementation specific" as to whether the threads are destroyed or not